# How can I left align with flushleft correctly?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, overleaf

[image]

**Problem: The bottom-left minipage is not aligned with the text above. I want it to be aligned.**

Here is the latex code:

```
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Heading}
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
AAAA BBBBBBB,\\
(CCCCCCC)\\
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD,\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
EEEE FFFFFFFFF,\\
(GGGGGG)\\
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH,\\
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put those `minipage`s inside the `abstract` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% for demo
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Heading}
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext

\vfill
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
AAAA BBBBBBB,\\
(CCCCCCC)\\
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD,\\
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
EEEE FFFFFFFFF,\\
(GGGGGG)\\
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH,\\
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of the `flushleft` and `flushright` environments, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` should be used (and no trailing ``\\``, but this is being picky).